# change number to english Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Hye, Can you check my script where is my problem..sorry I'm new in perl..I want to convert from number to english words for example 1400 -> one thousand four hundred...I already used

`Lingua::EN::Numbers qw(num2en num2en_ordinal);`

this is my input file.txt

```
I have us dollar 1200
```

and the output should be. "I have us dollar one thousand two hundred"

this is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use Lingua::EN::Numbers qw(num2en num2en_ordinal);

if(! open(INPUT, '< snuker.txt'))
{
die "cannot opent input file: $!";
}

select OUTPUT;

while($lines = <INPUT>){

$lines =~ s/usd|USD|Usd|uSd|UsD/us dollar/g;
$lines =~ s/\$/dollar /g;
$lines =~ s/rm|RM|Rm|rM/ringgit malaysia /g;
$lines =~ s/\n/ /g; 
$lines =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
$lines =~ s/(\d+)/num2en($lines)/g; #this is where it should convert to english words
    print lc($lines); #print lower case
}

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
close STDOUT;
```

the output i got is "`i have us dollar num2en(i have us dollar 1200 )`"

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to refer to the capture using `$1` instead of passing the `$lines` in your last regex where you also need an `e` flag at the end so that it is evaluated as an expression. You can use `i` flag to avoid writing all combinations of [Uu][Ss][Dd]...:

```
while($lines = <INPUT>){
  $lines =~ s/usd/us dollar/ig;
  $lines =~ s/\$/dollar /g;
  $lines =~ s/rm/ringgit malaysia /ig;
  $lines =~ s/\n/ /g; 
  $lines =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
  $lines =~ s/(\d+)/num2en($1)/ge; #this is where it should convert to english words
  print lc($lines), "\n"; #print lower case
}
```

Comment: +1, but I think the more important part to point out in your answer is, that you use `num2en($1)` instead of `num2en($lines)`.

Comment: ohh...I understand a bit now...sometimes when comes to regular expression, i'm getting blur because there are too many symbol..by the way, thanks for your answer..it works now...

Answer (score 5):

You’re missing the `e` modifier on the regex substitution:

```
$ echo foo 42 | perl -pe "s/(\d+)/\$1+1/g"
foo 42+1
$ echo foo 42 | perl -pe "s/(\d+)/\$1+1/ge"
foo 43
```

See [man perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> Options are as with m// with the addition of the following replacement
>   specific options:
>           e    Evaluate the right side as an expression.

Plus you have to refer to the captured number (`$1`), not the whole string (`$lines`), but I guess you have already caught that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are confusing regexps with functions. In the line where you try to do the conversion, you're not calling the function `num2en`; instead, you're replacing the number with the text `num2en($line)`. Here's a suggestion for you:

```
($text, $number) = $lines =~ s/(.*)+(\d+); # split the line into a text part and a number part
print lc($text . num2en($number));         # print first the text, then the converted number;
```